# Getting the raw code in xtext dsl

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I try to implement xtext dsl plugin based on existing interpreted language. The language already has an interpreter and I want to use it as it. The problem is, I can't see any stage where I can access the raw code and send it into interpretation. I noticed only the code generator with the doGenerate method, but it's not my case.

Appreciating your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to obtain the XtextResource from the parsed AST. It can provide the raw text.

```
MyModel model = ..
XtextResource res = (XtextResource)model.eResource();
String text = res.getParseResult().getRootNode().getText();
```